# Apexcharts not shown the Model

Tags: css, angular, typescript, apexcharts, angular15

Im using my Angular-15 and Bootstrap-5 papplication for the **[Apexchart](https://apexcharts.com/angular-chart-demos/radialbar-charts/basic/)**

The problem is with open the Model and  chart   not showing,
If I refresh page and browser zoom out 90% or Zoom in 100%  and then   chart is  is showing. but after refresh chart is again not showing.
Any solution for this?

*so when is model outside every chart is working and showing correctly*

Thanks

here the code

**.html**

```
<div #croSellWiseModal="bs-modal" aria-hidden="true" bsModal class="modal  fade" id="croSellWiseModal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content border-0 p-0">
      <!--<div class="modal-header p-4 pb-0">
       &lt;!&ndash; <h5 class="modal-title" >Cross-Selling


        </h5>&ndash;&gt;

        <button (click)="croSellWiseModal.hide()" class="btn-close"
                type="button"></button>
      </div>-->

      <div class="modal-body p-0 ">

            <div class="" style="height: auto;">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3" >
                  <div class="card h-100 border-0 shadow-none" style="background:#FFF2F6;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <p class="lg-q-link ">Cross-Selling
                          </p>

                      </div>
                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <p class="lg-q-link ">
                        Overall Score</p></div>


                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <ng-container >
                        <div class="apex-charts-ds">
                          <apx-chart
                            [series]="chartOptionsSell.series"
                            [chart]="chartOptionsSell.chart"
                            [plotOptions]="chartOptionsSell.plotOptions"
                            [responsive]="chartOptionsSell.responsive"
                            [colors]="['#F83E77']"

                          ></apx-chart>
                        </div>
                        </ng-container>
                      </div>

                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <p class=" lg-sub-ti   ">Total Contracts</p>



                      </div>

                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">


                        <p class=" counter-value-ss"><span class="counter-value-ss"
                        >151</span></p>

                      </div>



                      <div class="border-top mt-1"></div>


                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2">

                        <p class=" lg-sub-ti-b   ">Exclusive Contracts</p>


                      </div>



                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">



                        <p class=" counter-value-ss-b"><span class="counter-value-ss-b"
                        >91</span></p>
                      </div>



                      </div>
                  </div>


                </div>        <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="card h-100 border-0 shadow-none" >
                  <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
                  <p class="lg-q-link ">Cross-Selling
                  </p>

                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start"> <p class="lg-q-link ">
                Leader Board</p></div>

                <div class="mt-5">
              
                </div>      </div>      </div>
              </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end modal-content-->
  </div>

</div>
```

**.ts**

```
  @ViewChild('chartSell') chartSell!: ChartComponent;
  public chartOptionsSell: ChartOptions;
  public chartDataLoaded: boolean = false;


    //chartOptionsSell
    this.chartOptionsSell = {
      series: [60],
      chart: {
        type: 'radialBar',
        height: 210, // Adjust the height to make the chart smaller
      },
      plotOptions: {
        radialBar: {
          hollow: {
            size: '50%', // Adjust the size of the hollow portion
          },
          track: {
            background: '#FBD3DF', // Lighter red color for the remaining portion
          },
          dataLabels: {
            show: true,
            name: {
              show: false,
            },
            value: {
              color: '#0B5ED7',
              fontWeight: 600,
              fontSize: '20px',
              show: true,
              formatter: (val: any) => {
                return `${val}%`; // Customize the label format
              },
              offsetY: 5, // Adjust the vertical alignment
            },
            total: {
              show: false,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 210, // Adjust the breakpoint value for smaller screens
          options: {
            chart: {
              height: 120, // Adjust the height for smaller screens
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    };
```

Comment: What or when is `isChartLoading` turned? When is `chartSell` accessed? When is `chartOptionsSell` set? I am hinting, that component might not have been fully rendered yet before the page finishes reloading, and scrolling just triggers template refresh - that's why the component pops up.

Comment: @JoosepParts sorry for that, I updated the question and I forgot to remove that.but same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution,
I have removed the  `ng-container`  and added `d-flex` class

Here the updated solution

```
                <div class="d-flex apex-charts-ds">
                  <apx-chart
                    [series]="chartOptionsSell.series"
                    [chart]="chartOptionsSell.chart"
                    [plotOptions]="chartOptionsSell.plotOptions"
                    [responsive]="chartOptionsSell.responsive"
                    [colors]="['#F83E77']"

                  ></apx-chart>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue while triggering chart properties in `ngOnInit()`
I found a solution without modifying a template code.
The idea behind it is assignment of the `ChartOptions` properties while opening the ngx-bootstrap modal via ModalDirective.

Live example:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/intelligent-morning-xzpqzl